# Show empty elements in ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

Is it possible to show empty items in ListView in ASP.NET 4.0 ? For example, there are 2 items  in the datasource, but I want to show them + 2 other empty items.

Comment: Have you tried to bind an IEnumerable with empty objects?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible solution I can calculate how many items are in the datasource and add the empty items accordingly. But I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Why do you want to add as many empty items as items with data? That sounds like there is a better approach than the ListView.

Comment: 2 filled and 2 empty are just example. It could be 3 and 1. There is no correlation :) .

Comment: @Bogdna: i asked because you mentioned "accordingly" that sounds like a correlation. You only want to know how to add an empty string to a ListView? I think adding it to the datasource(only in memory) is the simpliest way.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ListView in a while, but when I need to add an additional item (blank or static) to a DropDownList that is bound to a data source, I use the "OnDataBound" event of the control. That event fires after the data is bound to the control. From that event, you can manipulate the data that has been added to the control, or add new records. I assume this would also work for a ListView. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.